# Running Batch File through java but process never completes

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder, openscad

I have built a single line batch file: openscad -o %1 %2.

This code works when I run: export output.stl input.scad from my command prompt.

I need this to run in java so i use the code:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", directory);

String command = "cmd export " + name + ".stl " + name + ".scad";

Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

directory is the location of all files associated with this process, the .bat, .scad, openscad.exe. And test.stl should output in this directory as well.

I get no errors from java by doing this but the export never happens.

Am I doing something wrong with how I run this code.
I know ProcessBuilder comes reccomended on similar posts but I don't know how the array works and can't find any good documentation or tutorials on running this.

Comment: is rt the same as  Runtime.getRuntime()?

Comment: rt comes from prior code: Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Comment: this [article](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1) says that the way you are doing it is older. you could set it up the way shown in the article?

Comment: Try to change `cmd export ....` into `cmd /c export ....`

Comment: I just tried it with that change and I get the same result

Comment: what does the export command do, and where is the executable for it, or is the bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + directory + "\\export.bat " + directory+ " " + name + ".stl " + name + ".scad");
```

Batch File:

```
cd %1
openscad.exe -o %2 %3
exit
```

start and entering the correct directory is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("export");
command.add(name+".stl");
command.add(name+".scad");

// get the output from the command
StringBuilder stdout = commandExecutor.getStandardOutputFromCommand();
StringBuilder stderr = commandExecutor.getStandardErrorFromCommand();

// print the output from the command
System.out.println("STDOUT");
System.out.println(stdout);
System.out.println("STDERR");
System.out.println(stderr);
```

Comment: this code compiles but has the same result. No exported file shows up. I put a print line after that bit and it reaches this with no errors.

Comment: what number is the "result" maybe that can give you a hint of what the issue is

Comment: -99 is what comes up. Where is the documentation about what this value means

Comment: [link](http://www.spacewalkproject.org/documentation/javadoc/com/redhat/rhn/manager/satellite/SystemCommandExecutor.html) try using the getLastCommandErrorMessage() method

Comment: I must have downloaded this library incorrectly. That method does not exist. Where did you import this library from.

Comment: but where do you download it from. This is not a base library in java so the source code has to be imported from somewhere and redhat doesn't have a download page that I can see.

Comment: edited post. looks like i was looking at the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to include the cmd bit. I have written a small example of how to provide an argument to the notepad executable in windows using a ProcessBuilder. It should be the same as what you are doing.

```
package test;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Starting");
        try
        {
            File f = new File("TestStuff.txt");
            f.createNewFile();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
            LinkedList<String> cmds = new LinkedList<String>();
            cmds.add("notepad");
            cmds.add("TestStuff.txt");
            pb.command(cmds);
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }   
}
```

This is the same as opening CMD and typing in notepad TestStuff.txt.

Also its important to note that some applications require you to read from their input streams in order for them to finish. If notepad operated like that, p.waitFor() would only return if the external process was killed. So be sure to read the input streams on the process.

I also tested this using various jar files like

```
....
cmds.add("java");
cmds.add("-jar");
cmds.add(pathToSomeExecutableJar);
....
```

granted I had included code to read from the streams like this:

```
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bsr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String s;
while ((s = bsr.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(s);
```